# How to enable API-KEY authorization for swagger UI created for ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui

I'm using swagger.net to create API documentation and want to enable API-KEY authentication to swagger UI.

So far, I have tried this:

```
public class SwaggerConfig
    {

        public static void Register()
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                    {
 c.ApiKey("apiKey", "header", "API Key Authentication", typeof(KeyAuthorizeAttribute));
                      }
}
}
```

KeyAuthorizeAttribute.cs file contains:

```
  public class KeyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
        {
            static string _password = null;
       
            private string Password
            {
                get
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_password))
                        _password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PASSWORD"];
                    return _password;
                }
            }

    

        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
            {
                IEnumerable<string> apiKey;
                if (actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("apiKey", out apiKey))
                {
                    return apiKey.First() == Password;
                }
                return false;
            }
            
    }
```

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PASSWORD"] value is set to 12345 in Web.config file

[image]

I'm able to get the authorize button, but it's accepting all random string, numbers  and get authorized than taking the password set in web.config file.

Suppose user enters api-key as "suyguhuus" ( any random string/numbers) it should be unauthorized and should only accept "PASSWORD" value defined in Web.config and allow user to communicate to its APIs only if the user is authorized.

Could anyone please assist with how to authorize above use case?